# Parse non-const char* to integer in C

Tags: c, string

I'm confused by the C library functions `strtol` etc. I am trying to use them on a `char*` buffer that I passed to a call to `strsep` (which changed the location of that pointer). However, the compiler complains that I am passing a `char*` to `strtol`, which expects a `const char*`.

How can I parse the string into an integer if it is not a `const char*`? I cannot use a constant in this case because I need, at times, to change the values in the array (and also `stringsep` will change where the beginning of the array points to). Thanks.

EDIT: Here's is my attempt, using `atoi` (I know this is now deprecated, but it takes the same type argument as `strtol` and I was going to get this to work before switching to the other function.)

```
char *token, *freeme;
    freeme = input;

    while((token = (char*)(uint64_t)strsep(&input, " ")) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);

        current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct fraction_node));
        current = current->next;

        current->num = atoi(strsep(&token, "/"));
        current->denom = atoi(&token);

    }
    free(freeme);
```

(The context is that it's parsing a list of fractions.)

Comment: Hmm, it's usually the other way around: error when passing a const pointer as a function parameter which is non-const.  Can you show your code and the context around it?

Comment: I edited with my code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while((token = (char*)(uint64_t)strsep(&input, " ")) != NULL) {
```

is completely broken.

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <string.h>

while((token = strsep(&input, " ") != NULL) {
```

is a trivial attempt to fix it, but does not work when `input` is a `char const *` pointer.

The

```
    current->denom = atoi(&token);
```

does not make sense either; you have to write

```
    current->denom = atoi(token);
```

Comment: Hmm, how can I rewrite it without casts? I thought the cast to uint64_t was necessary because this is on a 64-bit machine. Please let me know if I am wrong.

By the way, your second comment solved my problem. It turns out I misread the compiler error: it was complaining of char**, not char*. Thanks.

Comment: The fix you give for the while loop is actually what I had at first, but it did not compile on my machine. The error led me to believe that strsep was returning the wrong size pointer (not 64-bit as my machine requires), hence my cast. Please let me know if this is a mistake. Thanks

Comment: casts are evil and should be avoided as they can hide real errors.  Your casts are hiding exactly such an error (missing inclusion of <string.h> or missing `_BSD_SOURCE` feature macro).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the string first, before converting.